# Flutter android testing stuck on installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

ive been developing an app, but ive only been testing it on ios, and im planning on launching it soon, however i have started to attempt to test it on android, and whenever i try to run on an android emulator it gets stuck at installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone having this issue, what the problem was is that i was using API 33 for my emulator, which for some illogical reason stops the code from running, when I changed it to API 29 it worked.

Comment: Did you change the compileSDKversion? Or is there a field called API